# AngularJS double value in table

Tags: angularjs

I have problem with when I want print a table, I have a double value. This is my print on page:

A 2.14 2.14 B 4.57 C 6.00 6.00 D 3.43 E 3.86 F 3.29

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in liveCurrency">
    <td> {{item.currency}}</td>
    <td class="min-price" ng-show="isMin(item.price)">{{item.price}}</td>
    <td class="max-price" ng-show="isMax(item.price)">{{item.price}}</td>
    <td>{{item.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Which condition I have to set to overcome duplicate values? tnx for help

Comment: You are printing two times in your ng-repeat

Comment: I solved problem with ng-ih in last <td>

Comment: <td ng-if="isMin(item.price) == false && isMax(item.price)==false">{{item.price}}</td>

Answer (score 0):

The value is double printed because you have the `<td>{{item.price}}</td>` that will show every time **and** the `ng-show` directive that will be right at least once.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in liveCurrency">
    <td> {{item.currency}}</td>
    <td class="min-price" ng-show="isMin(item.price)">{{item.price}}</td>
    <td class="max-price" ng-show="isMax(item.price)">{{item.price}}</td>
    <!-- <td>{{item.price}}</td> -->
</tr>
```

If none of the show conditions are true, display your last `<td>`.

```
<td ng-if="!isMin(item.price) && !isMax(item.price)>{{item.price}}</td>
```